# Target input types - SASS

Tags: html, css, forms

I got css file that needed to convert sass. I've handled basics css styles but stuck with this code block. It has a input tag styles.

```
.search-box input[type='text']{
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
}
     .search-box input[type='text']:focus{
        outline: 0;
    }
    .search-box input[type='text']::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: #000000;
    }
    .search-box input[type='text']::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+
        color: #000000;
    }
    .search-box  input[type='text']:-ms-input-placeholder {
        color: #000000;
    }
```

So I've researched and convert into sass like this.

```
.search-box {
    input[type='text'] {
        font-size: 16px;
        background-color: #fff;
        &:focus {
            outline: 0;
        }
        &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
            color: #000000;
        }
        &::-moz-placeholder {
            color: #000000;
        }
        &:-ms-input-placeholder {
            color: #000000;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to know that there is a best practice for styling form input tags And did I convert it wrong way here? Please

Comment: For checking the right conversion you can use Online Compiler like this [**Official Complier(sassmeister)**](http://www.sassmeister.com)

Comment: Looks like you've done just fine. Although, your sass misses the `padding: 3px 5px;` line! It compiles fine, though, as @vivekkupadhyay has shown.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I can suggest one improvement - create a mixin for placeholder, so you won't need to repeat code 3 times

Comment: @DenisSheremet Interesting! Can you show me the way by submitting as a answer ?I'm bit new to sass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Little improvement to your code

```
@mixin placeholder {
    &::-webkit-input-placeholder {@content}
    &::-moz-placeholder {@content}
    &:-moz-placeholder {@content}
    &:-ms-input-placeholder {@content}
}

.search-box {
    input[type='text'] {
        font-size: 16px;
        background-color: #fff;
        &:focus {
            outline: 0;
        }
        @include placeholder {
            color: #000000;
        }
    }
}
```